# Most correct/simple/used/cleanest way to make a login/register form (Divs/Others)

Tags: html, css, authentication

I'm still young when it comes to coding, and I've heard multiple things about organization. Some use section's and some use div's, some use a div for buttons, other use the inputs in css to change it. As someone who likes to do his code clean and simple to understand, yet correct, this sometimes bothers me.

What is the best way to make a login form, with the for example the maximum of remember me and a button, with a text under saying "You don't have an account yet? Register here".

Should I use divs, sections, or both? What are the orders of the divs/sections? Container, Login, buttons?

Example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="login">
        <form>
            <input text>
            <remember me>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <input submits>
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this correct? Is there a way of doing it more organized?

What the most correct, used, simple and clean way to make it?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap makes it really easy to do forms w/ minimal styling, with the exception of `font sizes`, `colors`, etc, but they add extra `elements`, like the `form-group` so you don't have to add extra CSS. I like to always use `article`, `header`, `section`, `footer`, etc whenever I can.

I understand that `div` is basically a "whatever" element. Bootstrap uses `divs` throughout their examples, but just b/c it's a `div` on THEIR example, doesn't mean you cannot use something else.

It also depends a whole lot on your layout. Perhaps you have the login on one page, but you have background images, centering the login form, etc, so this will determine which types of elements that you use.

```
<div id="login">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" />
    </div>
    <div> class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
       <input type="checkbox" />
       <label>Remember Me</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </div>
</div>
```

This could easily be turned into

```
<article id="login">
    <section class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" />
    </section>
    <section  class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" />
    </section>
    <section class="form-group form-inline">
       <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" />
       <label>Remember Me</label>
    </section>
    <footer class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </footer>
</article>
```

I tend to like the latter, but it's your decision really.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on 'what you use' and 'what you want to end with'.
If you want to add a complex css stylesheet or most of the work will be done on the server side, then you should better have a detailed composition. 
In another hand, if you plan to use javascript and few css, the clearest the best.

To me, the login part (or its container, ie a header) of your page should be a section. The divs should be used to organize the inner-elements.

"The  tag defines sections in a document, such as chapters, headers, footers, or any other sections of the document."
[http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_section.asp]

Answer (score 0):

I depends really basicly what you can handle better.